# What determines the value of AVCaptureConnection.isVideoOrientationSupported?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having some issues with adjusting video orientation in my app. I use this check when adjusting the orientation. I know the 'connection' property is not supported below iOS 6.0; but some users are reporting issues with a much newer iOS version. I'm wondering if isVideoOrientationSupported can itself be false on some phones -- and if so, why? I haven't found any documentation online about it.

```
if previewLayer.connection!.isVideoOrientationSupported {

    previewLayer.connection!.videoOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
}
```